# error: ‘SIZE’ cannot appear in a constant-expression when using template< class T, int MAX_SIZE >

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, static-variables

I am getting a compilation error:

```
HuffTree.cpp:43:20: error: ‘SIZE’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
  PQueue<HuffNode*, SIZE>;
```

where the involved lines are:

```
void HuffTree::buildTree(char * chs, int * freqs, int size )
{
static const int SIZE = size;
PQueue<HuffNode*, SIZE>;
```

I've tried all different types for "`SIZE`"

```
PQueue<HuffNode*, size>; // From the method parameter
static const int SIZE = static_cast<int>(size);
```

etc. But the only the following compiles:

```
PQueue<HuffNode*, 10>; // Or any other random int
```

I also get the related error:

```
HuffTree.cpp:43:24: error: template argument 2 is invalid
PQueue<HuffNode*, SIZE>;
```

`PQueue` is a template class accepting:

```
template< class T, int MAX_SIZE >
PQueue(T* items, int size);
```

What type does '`size`' need to be for the argument to be accepted?
Using c++11

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: I'm using a template class PQueue, which is a priority queue, and filling it with a const HuffNode. I end up using this for a Huffman Tree, but that's not super relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
PQueue<HuffNode*, SIZE>;
```

is a type and require a `SIZE` known at compile time.

If you declare `SIZE` with a value known compile time, as in

```
PQueue<HuffNode*, 10>;
```

or also in

```
static const int SIZE = 10;
PQueue<HuffNode*, SIZE>;
```

it should works.

But if `SIZE` depend from a value, `size`, known only run-time (the input value of a function method is considered to be known runtime), the compiler can't known `SIZE` compile time.

Addendum: you're using C++11; so try using `constexpr` instead of `const`

```
static constexpr int SIZE = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign `size` to the `static const` variable `SIZE` every time you enter the member. You have to give `SIZE` a value *once* when you create it, like `static const int SIZE = 10;`. I'd suggest declaring it outside your member:

```
const int MAX_SIZE = 10;

// ...

void HuffTree::buildTree(char * chs, int * freqs, int size )
{
    HuffNode* n = new HuffNode(/* args */);
    PQueue<HuffNode, MAX_SIZE> queue(n, size); // HuffNode in template, not HuffNode*

}
```

Comment: Wrong. The instruction `static const int SIZE = size;` is executed only the first time `HuffTree::buildTree` is executed; the problem is another: is that `SIZE` is initialized with a value (`size`) known only run-time where in `PQueue<HuffNode*, SIZE>;` must be known compile-time. If you change the initialization of `SIZE` in `static const int SIZE = 10;`, leaving it inside the method, the error should disappear.

Comment: I see how what I said could be misinterpreted. What I meant to say was that the OP is clearly trying to assign the argument `size` to `SIZE`, but it doesn't do what OP thinks it does. In addition, `PQueue` takes two template arguments (the second being `MAX_SIZE`), but the way it is being instantiated suggests that `SIZE` should provide the value for `MAX_SIZE`, but again this is misleading. That is why I suggested moving it outside the function so that it is clear what the intent is. Not to mention that `PQueue<HuffNode*, SIZE>;` makes no sense as it does not declare anything.

Comment: You're right: I've misinterpreted what you said; sorry (down-vote removed; I've edited your answer to remove my downvote). But I'm not agree with you regarding "you trying [...] every time you enter the member"; (reasonable interpretation but we don't what the OP want) and, moreover, I think is better (more clearer) a `static const(expr) int` variable with a constant value inside the method that a global constant outside.

Comment: Fair enough, and no offence taken - I should have phrased it more clearly. Thank you for pointing it out!